# What is the std::chrono::time_point equivalent of std::numeric_limits::infinity()?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Suppose I want to call `my_func()` periodically at `CALL_PERIOD` intervals

```
auto last_call_time = CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
while (true)
{
    if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - last_call_time > CALL_PERIOD)
    {
        last_call_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        my_func();
    }
}
```

What would be an appropriate `CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY` such that the line

```
std::chrono::system_clock::now() - last_call_time > CALL_PERIOD
```

will always evaluate `true` on the first run?

I've tried [`time_point::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/min) but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Besides the logical error that's been pointed out (the initialization belongs before the `while` loop), have you considered the trivial logical observation that calling `call_my_func()` before the while loop will achieve the same exact logical results you're trying to implement with your approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the main reasons to have a type like `std::optional` is so that we don't have to have hacks like picking a specific value to mean "not a value":

```
std::optional<std::chrono::system_clock::time_point> last_call_time;
while (true)
{
    auto curr = std::chrono::system_clock::now()
    if (!last_call_time || (curr - *last_call_time) > CALL_PERIOD)
    {
        last_call_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        my_func();
    }
}
```

If C++17 is not available to you, and/or you're just dead-set on using the old hack of picking a special value, you can get the clock's `rep` type and compute the minimum possible integer of it:

```
using sys_clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
constexpr auto min_int = std::numeric_limits<sys_clock::rep>::min();
constexpr sys_clock::duration min_duration(min_int);
sys_clock::time_point min_time(min_duration);
```

Of course, `min_time` is still a valid time, so it's unlike any "infinity" representation for `float`s.

Answer (score 2):

The rationale that there is no `time_point::infinity` equivalent is that `time_point`s are simple wrappers around arithmetic types.  Simplistic wrappers lead to the highest performing code.  And this same rationale is also a clue that for special cases, `time_point::infinity` actually *does* exist!

Let me elaborate further on that entirely confusing first paragraph...

`system_clock::time_point` is a simple wrapper around a `duration`.  Exactly which `duration` is unspecified, but let's just say it is `nanoseconds`.  And `nanoseconds` is a simple wrapper around a 64 bit signed integer (say `long long`).

`long long` has no representation of +/- `INFINITY`.  But it *does* have a minimum value:  -9223372036854775808.

A shortcut for putting this value into a `duration` (say `nanoseconds`) is `nanoseconds::min()`, and a shortcut to putting this value into `system_clock::time_point` is `system_clock::time_point::min()`.

However when you do so, it is an invitation for plain old signed integral overflow.  After all:

```
cout << (10 - numeric_limits<long long>::min() > 1) << '\n';
```

overflows and prints out `0` (false).  And that's precisely why:

```
auto CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = system_clock::time_point::min();
```

didn't work.

There are several ways to get your code to work.  Which is best for your application is up to you.  But now that `<chrono>` is just a little less mysterious, you can better make that decision.

Perhaps the easiest way is to set `CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY` to something that isn't quite so negative so that you don't risk overflow:

```
auto CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - CALL_PERIOD;
```

C++20 standardizes the existing practice that `system_clock`'s epoch is 1970-01-01, so here's another possibility (that works back to C++11):

```
// Set CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
auto CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point{};
```

But let's say that for some reason you really, really need a `time_point` that is infinitely in the past.  You can do that too, it just takes a little more work.  `float` and `double` are arithmetic types too, and they *do* have a representation of `INFINITY`!  So you can just build a `time_point` out of one of those types.

```
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;
using tp_dsec = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, dsec>;
auto CHRONO_NEGATIVE_INFINITY = tp_dsec{dsec{-INFINITY}};
```

The first line makes `dsec` a name for double-based-seconds.  The second line makes `tp_dsec` a name for a `system_clock`-based `time_point` using `dsec` as its representation.  And then the third line just stuffs negative infinity into a `tp_dsec`.  The rest of your code will implicitly convert to double-based `time_point`s and `duration`s when doing the test.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your test like this:

```
auto last_call_time = std::chrono::system_clock::min();
...
if (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - CALL_PERIOD > last_call_time)
```

you shouldn't overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use 0:

```
std::chrono::duration CALL_PERIOD(std::chrono::seconds(2));
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point last_call_time; //auto init to 0,
// or can use explicit initialization to 0:
//   std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point last_call_time(std::chrono::seconds(0));
while (true)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    if (now - last_call_time > CALL_PERIOD)
    {
        last_call_time = now;
        my_func();
    }
}
```